# CakePHP 2 RSS feed from multiple controllers

Tags: cakephp, rss, cakephp-2.0

I've created an RSS feed with the RssHelper as in http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/rss.html. It is located at app/View/Posts/rss/index.ctp and is accessible at
/posts/index.rss It shows RSS feeds from Posts.

I have also created RSS feed for other controllers like news, events etc. I want to let users subscribe to RSS feed that shows all the feeds from other contollers like news, events etc. That is I want to combine RSS feeds from different controllers.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Within any Controller's action, you can load other models - for example, in your PostsController, something like this:

```
//PostsController
public function rss_combined() {
    $this->loadModel('Event');
    $this->loadModel('News');
    //do whatever logic you want to create a combined RSS
}
```

Or, if the models are associated with the `Post` model, you can access methods through the `Post` model:

```
// Instead of this:
$this->loadModel('Event');
$this->Event->myMethod();

// You can do this:
$this->Post->Event->myMethod();
```

Often I create a `DashboardsController` or something of the like when I need many things that aren't tied directly to a specific model.  Then, you can specify that the Dashboard model [doesn't use a database table](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable):

```
public $useTable = false;
```